# Не работает else | python aiogram sqlite3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

Проверяю, есть ли пользователь в бд и в зависимости от результата проверки должны выполнятся разные функции, но else просто игнорируется. Может я что-то не вижу? Если в if убирать "not", то будет выполняться только вторая функция. Ищу решение уже несколько часов...
Код:

```
import sqlite3
import random

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
    def user_ex(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'ferma' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
```

```
import config
import logging
import random
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from db import Database

#log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#Инициализация бота
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database('database.db')


@dp.message_handler(commands = ['farm'])
async def farm(message: types.Message):
    orens = random.randint(4, 50)
    balance = 0
    if (not db.user_ex(message.from_user.id)):       
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.username, orens)
        await message.answer("Вы заработали " + str(orens) + " оренов!")
    else:        
        await message.answer("Вы уже есть в базе!")

#run long-polling
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: А почему ты думаешь, что ветка else должна выполняться?

Comment: потому-что пользователь с таким айди будет нейден в бд

Comment: Ну так а ты вообще проверил, что у тебя if выдает? Или программируешь наугад?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в запросе. Должно быть:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ferma WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
```

Значение в одинарных кавычках в SQL трактуется, как строковый литерал, а вам нужно, сравнивать с колонкой в таблице. Для этого нужно использовать поле или без кавычек вообще или в двойных кавычках. У вас же получается сравнение строки `'user_id'` буквально со значением в переменной `user_id`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я проверил гайд по которому делал и там кавычки есть. Очень странно, но главное, что заработало